# XSLT for-each loops with dynamic filters

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is a simplified version of an XML-Message (SAP-IDOC) i need to transform into a more easy to read XML as the example below.

It is a SAP Delivery IDOC that gives me the information for a shipment and its positions. The Problem is, that it could be that Position 10 and 20 are in the same carton (E1EDL37) and have a different Tracking Number (Field TRACKN) than position 3.

```
<DELVRY07>
<IDOC>
    <E1EDL20> <!-- Contains all positions-->
        <E1EDL24> <!--one Node for each position -->
            <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
            <MATNR>123</MATNR>
            <E1EDL41>
                <BSTNR>Fall 1</BSTNR>
            </E1EDL41>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24><!--one Node for each position -->
            <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
            <MATNR>456</MATNR>
            <E1EDL41>
                <BSTNR>Fall 2</BSTNR>
            </E1EDL41>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24><!--one Node for each position -->
            <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
            <MATNR>789</MATNR>
            <E1EDL41>
                <BSTNR>Fall 3</BSTNR>
            </E1EDL41>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL37><!--one Node for every carton-->
            <E1EDL49>
                <XSITD>UPS1</XSITD>
                <TRACKN>Track 1</TRACKN>
            </E1EDL49>
            <E1EDL44><!-- every position in the carton-->
                <VBELN>123456</VBELN>
                <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
            </E1EDL44>
            <E1EDL44><!-- every position in the carton-->
                <VBELN>456789</VBELN>
                <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
            </E1EDL44>
        </E1EDL37>
        <E1EDL37><!--one Node for every carton-->
            <E1EDL49>
                <XSITD>DPD</XSITD>
                <TRACKN>Track 2</TRACKN>
            </E1EDL49>
            <E1EDL44><!-- every position in the carton-->
                <VBELN>123456</VBELN>
                <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
            </E1EDL44>
        </E1EDL37>
    </E1EDL20>
</IDOC>
</DELVRY07>
```

this should be the xml message after the xslt transformation (or a similar message):

```
<Shipment>
    <Positions>
        <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
        <MATNR>123</MATNR>
        <BSTNR>Fall 1</BSTNR>
        <TRACKN>Track 1</TRACKN>
        <XSITD>UPS1</XSITD>
    </Positions>
    <Positions>
        <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
        <MATNR>456</MATNR>
        <BSTNR>Fall 2</BSTNR>
        <TRACKN>Track 1</TRACKN>
        <XSITD>UPS1</XSITD>
    </Positions>
    <Positions>
        <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
        <MATNR>123</MATNR>
        <BSTNR>Fall 3</BSTNR>
        <TRACKN>Track 2</TRACKN>
        <XSITD>DPD</XSITD>
    </Positions>
</Shipment>
```

I tried to go through the E1EDL24 Elements with a loop and write the information in variables. But from then on I would need to do a loop over all E1EDL44 and get the value of the TRACKN field of the E1EDL49 Element above.

Can you please help me to find a way to do this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow this correctly (which is not at all certain), you want to do create a record for each "position" and fetch additional data from the matching "carton":

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="carton-by-position" match="E1EDL37" use="E1EDL44/POSNR" />

<xsl:template match="/DELVRY07">
    <Shipment>
        <xsl:for-each select="IDOC/E1EDL20/E1EDL24">
            <Positions>
                <xsl:copy-of select="POSNR | MATNR | E1EDL41/BSTNR"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('carton-by-position', POSNR)/E1EDL49/*"/>
            </Positions>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Shipment>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/IDOC/E1EDL20">
    <xsl:variable name="parent" select="."/>
    <Shipment>
      <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL24/POSNR">
        <xsl:variable name="posnr" select="."/>
        <Position>
          <POSNR><xsl:value-of select="$posnr"/></POSNR>
          <MATNR><xsl:value-of select="../MATNR"/></MATNR>
          <BSTNR><xsl:value-of select="../E1EDL41/BSTNR"/></BSTNR>
          <TRACKN><xsl:value-of select="$parent/E1EDL37[E1EDL44/POSNR=$posnr]/E1EDL49/TRACKN"/></TRACKN>
          <XSITD><xsl:value-of select="$parent/E1EDL37[E1EDL44/POSNR=$posnr]/E1EDL49/XSITD"/></XSITD>
        </Position>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Shipment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online-Fiddle here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamKV)